# How do I set c flags in the Rakefile for compilation of extensions via extension task?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile, ruby-c-extension

I have a [`Rakefile`](https://github.com/abinashmeher999/symengine/blob/ruby_file_structure/src/ruby/Rakefile) on Github:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/package_task'
require 'bundler'

Bundler::GemHelper.install_tasks

require 'rake'
require 'rake/extensiontask'

Rake::ExtensionTask.new do |ext|
    ext.name = 'symengine'
    ext.ext_dir = 'ext/symengine'
    ext.lib_dir = 'lib/'
    ext.source_pattern = "**/*.{c,cpp, h}"
end

gemspec = eval(IO.read("symengine.gemspec"))

Gem::PackageTask.new(gemspec).define
```

I have all the dependencies installed. Every time I execute `rake compile` I get an error like this:

```
make
linking shared-object symengine/symengine.so
/usr/bin/ld: symengine.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `cbasic_alloc' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [symengine.so] Error 1
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (2): [make...]
/home/abinashmeher999/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-compiler-0.9.5/lib/rake/extensiontask.rb:155:in `block (2 levels) in define_compile_tasks'
/home/abinashmeher999/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rake-compiler-0.9.5/lib/rake/extensiontask.rb:154:in `block in define_compile_tasks'
Tasks: TOP => compile => compile:x86_64-linux => compile:symengine:x86_64-linux => copy:symengine:x86_64-linux:2.2.0 => tmp/x86_64-linux/symengine/2.2.0/symengine.so
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have a hint that I am missing the `-fPIC` flag for compilation. cmake files usually add this (I think). I don't know where and how to set the flags in the `Rakefile`.